# Insertar datos en dos tablas desde un excel laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

estoy tratando de importar datos de un excel en dos tablas, de momento puedo insertar en una tabla  ese array de datos pero no se como hacer para insertar datos en otra tabla relacionada a esta misma, el codigo que uso para insertar en la primera tabla es la siguente:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
   
    return  User::updateOrCreate([
        
        'n_control' => $row[0],
        'nombre'    => $row[1],
        'apellidop' => $row[2],
        'apellidom' => $row[3],
        'email'     => $row[4],
        'rol'       => 'ALUMNO',

    ]);

    Alumno::updateOrCreate([
        
        'carrera' => $rows[5],
        'id'    => $ultimo_r, /// id del registro de Usuario
        

    ]);

}
```

quiero obtener el id de ese array en una tabla que esta relacionada con esa tabla para insertar otro dato que estarian dentro de ese array.

Comment: ¿Probaste hacerlo antes del return?

Comment: si, solo que no se como sacar todos los id correspondientes a esa insercion

Comment: Esa acción genera un objeto no?, de ser así entonces asignalo a una variable y posterior puedes hacer esto: `$variable->id` y así puedes tomar el id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder realizar la inserción del array, se ejecuta de la siguiente forma, agregando las siguientes líneas:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
```

Y en el formulario se  escribira de la siguiente manera

```
$idUser=user::updateOrCreate([
        'n_control'     => $row[0],
        'nombre'        => $row[1],
        'apellidop'     => $row[2],
        'apellidom'     => $row[3],
        'email'         => $row[4],
        'rol'           => 'ALUMNO',
    ]);

    $idAlumno = Alumno::updateOrCreate([      
        'carrera'   => $row[5],
        'id'        => $idUser->id,

    ]);
```